# Deck.gl TileLayer (WMS) only processing preflight responses

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, fetch-api, deck.gl

In my Angular 16 app, I'd like to display a WMS layer on a Google Map with Deck.gl - through a combination of [`TileLayer`](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/tile-layer)s and [`BitmapLayer`](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/bitmap-layer)s.

Here's my `TileLayer` config:

```js
import { TileLayer } from "@deck.gl/geo-layers/typed";
import { GeoBoundingBox } from "@deck.gl/geo-layers/typed/tileset-2d";
import { BitmapLayer } from "@deck.gl/layers/typed";
import { parse } from "@loaders.gl/core";

const wmsLayer = new TileLayer({
    id: "xyz",
    tileSize: 256,
    opacity: 0.8,
    renderSubLayers: (props: any) => {
        const { west, south, east, north } = props.tile.bbox;
        return new BitmapLayer(props, {
            image: props.data,
            transparentColor: [255, 255, 255, 0],
            bounds: [west, south, east, north],
        });
    },
    getTileData: async ({ bbox, signal }) => {
        const { west, south, north, east } = bbox as GeoBoundingBox;

        const params = [
            "?Request=GetMap",
            "&Service=WMS",
            "&crs=EPSG:4326",
            "&width=256",
            "&height=256",
            "&dpi=300",
            "&format=image/png",
            "&transparent=TRUE",
            `&BBOX=${[west, south, east, north].join(",")}`,
        ];
        const targetUrl = process.env.WMS_BASE + params.join("");

        const data = await fetch(targetUrl, {
            signal,
        });

        if (signal?.aborted) {
            return null;
        }

        if (data.type === "cors") {
            // Every data response seems to be of type `cors`   
            return null;
        }

        return parse(data);
    },
});
```

The issue is, [`getTileData`](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/tile-layer#gettiledata) isn't handling CORS properly because it seems to only pass resolved requests whose response is of [`type: "cors"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type):

[image: getTileData breakpoint]

Note that the initial preflight requests (`OPTIONS`) plus the subsequent `GET`s all resolve with 200s but only preflight `fetch` is passed downstream:
[image]

How can I ignore preflight requests and let `getTileData` only process the actual GET requests?

FYI I'm on v8.9.30 and here's my package.json :

```json
"@deck.gl/aggregation-layers": "^8.9.30",
"@deck.gl/carto": "^8.9.30",
"@deck.gl/core": "^8.9.30",
"@deck.gl/experimental-layers": "^6.4.10",
"@deck.gl/extensions": "^8.9.30",
"@deck.gl/geo-layers": "^8.9.30",
"@deck.gl/google-maps": "^8.9.30",
"@deck.gl/layers": "^8.9.30",
"@deck.gl/mesh-layers": "^8.9.30",
"@loaders.gl/core": "^3.4.14",
"@luma.gl/core": "^8.5.21",
```

PS - I don't have a repro because the services are behind VPNs and auth walls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR there's nothing wrong with `getTileData` or `fetch`. It's a matter of processing Blobs and/or array buffers.

##### Learnings

1. Beginner's mistake: **the `fetch` response must be `await`ed**. Obtaining an image `Blob` goes like this:

   ```js
   const resp = await fetch(...);
   const blob = await resp.blob();
   ```
2. **There's nothing wrong with a response of `type: "cors"`** – such responses indicate that they were *received from a valid cross-origin request*.
3. Blob's cannot easily be parsed by `parse()` or `load()` of `@loaders.gl/core`. However, **`getTileData` may return a `Blob` and pass it to `renderSubLayers`**.
4. `renderSubLayers`'s `BitmapLayer` [cannot load `Blob`s *directly*](https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/loading-data#load-resource-without-an-url). **But you can pass [Object URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static)**, namely: `URL.createObjectURL(props.data)`.

---

Here's the working code:

```js
import { GeoBoundingBox, TileLayer } from "@deck.gl/geo-layers/typed";
import { BitmapLayer } from "@deck.gl/layers/typed";

const wmsLayer = new TileLayer({
    id: "xyz",
    tileSize: 256,
    opacity: 0.8,
    renderSubLayers: (props: any) => {
        const { west, south, east, north } = props.tile.bbox;
        return new BitmapLayer(props, {
            //     ⬇️⬇️⬇️
            image: URL.createObjectURL(props.data as Blob),
            transparentColor: [255, 255, 255, 0],
            bounds: [west, south, east, north],
        });
    },
    getTileData: async ({ bbox, signal }) => {
        const { west, south, north, east } = bbox as GeoBoundingBox;
        const params = [
            "...",
            `&BBOX=${[west, south, east, north].join(",")}`,
        ];
        const targetUrl = process.env.WMS_BASE + params.join("");
        const resp = await fetch(targetUrl, { signal });
        //           ⬇️⬇️⬇️
        const blob = resp?.blob;
        if (signal?.aborted || !blob) {
            return null;
        }

        // ⬇️⬇️⬇️
        return blob;
    },
});
```